# Parameter passed from android code using KSoap to asmx service getting null at service definition (at .Net Side)

Tags: android, .net, asmx, ksoap

I'm calling asmx service from android using ksoap library also I'm passing some parameters to that service but I'm getting all parameters EMPTY (i.e. "") in service definition. If I print request object in my android code before calling asmx service it is showing correct value, but getting empty parameters in service definition.

```
    ***My Android code is--***

public final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://www.example.com/abc/";
public final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://www.example.com/abc/WS.asmx";

public final String TEST_OPERATION="ServiceName";
public final String TEST_SOAP_ACTION="http://www.example.com/abc/ServiceName";  

public String ServiceName(String strParam1, String strParam2)
{
    ***// following Log printing correct value***
    Log.w("*******", "strParam1= "+strParam1+", strParam2= "+strParam2);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,TEST_OPERATION);
    PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("strParam1");
    pi.setValue(strParam1);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    pi=new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("strParam2");
    pi.setValue(strParam2);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);        

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    ***// Following statement printing correct value***     
    Log.w("request= ", request.toString());
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    Object response=null;
    try
    {
        httpTransport.call(TEST_SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = envelope.getResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        response=exception.toString();
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

***My .Net code (i.e service defination) is ---***

```
    [WebMethod]
     public String ServiceName(string strParam1, string strParam2)
     {
         try
         {
             string Con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
             SqlConnection sn = new SqlConnection(Con);
             if (sn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                 sn.Close();
             sn.Open();
             SqlTransaction trans = sn.BeginTransaction();

             try
             {
                 ***// Following statement inserting EMPTY value in to the database***
                 Generic.db.DepositTransaction_insert(strParam1, strParam2, "INSERT");

                 return "Record Save Successfully";
             }

             catch (Exception ex)
             {

                 return ex.ToString();
             }
         }

    catch (Exception ex)
        {
                 return ex.ToString();
        }
}
```

Hope you understand what I'm trying to say..! Please help.. Thank you..!

Comment: Android code looks ok, I use : request.addProperty("strParam1",strParam1);  should make no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. It was just a spelling mistake. See first 4 lines of my android code as

```
public final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://www.example.com/abc/";
public final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://www.example.com/abc/WS.asmx";

public final String TEST_OPERATION="ServiceName";
public final String TEST_SOAP_ACTION="http://www.example.com/abc/ServiceName";
```

it contains string as ***www.example.com*** it ***should be www.Example.com*** (It is Case sensitive)